# Errors in Specflow reports template

Tags: c#, .net, razor, specflow

When Stetting up a Specflow project I am facing an error where the default Specflow report works fine but as soon as I implement my own version of it using the `ReportTemplate.cshtml` file it throws loads of errors claiming `Specflow`, `helper` and `TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestSuiteStructure` and other library's cant be found and I cant seem to figure out why because they are there (surely my Specflow tests would not run if Specflow was not installed and the default report would not generate perfectly). Any help appreciated as I am new To Specflow reports.

using .NET Core 3.1

.csproj

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.9.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Protractor" Version="0.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.10.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.1.82" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.1.82" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecRun.Runner" Version="3.1.48" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecRun.SpecFlow" Version="3.1.48" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

.runsettings file:

```
  <!-- Configurations for SpecFlow+ Runner -->
  <SpecRun>
    <Profile>./RunSettings/FAKE.srprofile</Profile>
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
    <ReportFile>Jacks_Sample_Reports_Template.html</ReportFile>
    <GenerateSpecRunTrait>false</GenerateSpecRunTrait>
    <GenerateFeatureTrait>false</GenerateFeatureTrait>
  </SpecRun>
</RunSettings>
```

.srprofile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestProfile xmlns="http://www.specflow.org/schemas/plus/TestProfile/1.5">
  <Settings projectName="PLACEHOLDER_NOTREAL" reportTemplate=".\\..\\..\\..\\RunSettings\\JacksSampleTemplate.cshtml"/>
  <!-- Look at this website for execution configurations : "https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlowPlus-Resources/wiki/Execution"-->
  <Execution stopAfterFailures="3" testThreadCount="1" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" retryCount="0" />
  <!-- For collecting by a SpecRun server update and enable the following element. For using the 
      collected statistics, set testSchedulingMode="Adaptive" attribute on the <Execution> element.
    <Server serverUrl="http://specrunserver:6365" publishResults="true" />
  -->
  <TestAssemblyPaths>
    <TestAssemblyPath>FAKE.dll</TestAssemblyPath>
  </TestAssemblyPaths>
  <DeploymentTransformation>
    <Steps>
      <!-- sample config transform to change the connection string-->
      <!--<ConfigFileTransformation configFile="App.config">
        <Transformation>
          <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                            <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
                <connectionStrings>
                  <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseForTesting;Integrated Security=True" 
                       xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionString)" />
                </connectionStrings>
                            </configuration>
                        ]]>
        </Transformation>
      </ConfigFileTransformation>-->
    </Steps>
  </DeploymentTransformation>
</TestProfile>
```

[image]

The list of errors go on but i'm fairly certain they are due to missing librarys

Comment: Are you getting these errors only when editing the `cshtml` file or when you generate the report?

Comment: These errors are generated when I create the cshtaml file in my project using the template but with no modifications. When I complete a test run the report is generated but it is not from the file in my project and is also named "TestRunReport.html" instead of the name i specified. a text file is also created with the name of (what i thought should have been the name of my report).

Comment: The text file Just contains information about the test run and specifies at the end that it is generating the report mentioned above. i can post it if you think that would be useful. Thanks in advance for the help.